# duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default error where is the duplicate?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I think I'm probably having a brainfart but the solution is evading me for now.
On startup, Nginx is returning the following error in journalctl.

"A duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default"

I can't see the duplicate for default.
This is my sites-enabled default file can anyone else point me to the cause of the error?

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

server_name _;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}


}


server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name demo4.review;

root /var/www/static;
index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}

server {

    server_name wp.demo4.review;

    root /var/www/wp_demo;

      location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }



listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wp.demo4.review/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wp.demo4.review/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
if ($host = wp.demo4.review) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name wp.demo4.review;
return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
listen 80;
    server_name api.demo4.review;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}



server {
if ($host = wp.demo4.review) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot



    server_name wp.demo4.review;
listen 80;
return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


server {

    server_name ukl.demo4.review;

    root /var/www/ukl;

   ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }



listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ukl.demo4.review/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ukl.demo4.review/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
if ($host = ukl.demo4.review) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot



    server_name ukl.demo4.review;
listen 80;
return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all files. Is there another `default_server` defined in your `nginx.conf` file perhaps? Or is there an editor's backup file that Nginx is inadvertently reading?

Comment: IT was exactly that, their was a .save copy that nginx was already reading.

Comment: You really have a duplicate `server` block, lines 76-89 and 105-117 of your config file.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error and when I look into the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder there is a duplicated file that was created by default removing that file solves the problem:

```
ubuntu@2172-web-01:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default-:22
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
ubuntu@2172-web-01:~$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
ubuntu@2172-web-01:/etc/nginx/sites-enableds ls
default default~
ubuntu@2172-web-01:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo rm default
ubuntu@2172-web-01:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a default.save file in the same directory that Nginx was also reading.